# Codeigniter Imagick warning on godaddy linux hosting

Tags: linux, php, cpanel, godaddy

I am using godaddy linux cpanel hosting and install fresh copy of codeigniter .

And getting the following error on each session.

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Core Warning
Message: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/imagick.so' 
- libMagickWand.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Filename: Unknown
Line Number: 0
Backtrace:
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Godaddy Hosting with Cpanel

Go to

> Cpanel -> Software -> Select PHP Version

select PHP Version to **5.5** and **set as current** 
also you can enable **imagick** extention from there

Answer (score 0):

This was the same issue which I was getting on one of my site. Creating a support ticket to the hosting company they replied me with a solution that reinstalling the imagemagick on the server removed that error. I advice you to contact the support and talk regarding this with.

> vivek shah: Whatwas the issue 11:55
>
> MTH Operator: I have reinstall imagemagick on the server